# Merge Query in oracle throws "ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 64 in tablespace TEMP"

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

We are using a one-time merge query in oracle 12c which fetches around "22633334" records of data and updates it in the target table, but every time when the query run's it throws "ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 64 in tablespace TEMP" issue, the DBA has already extended it to 60 GB. Can anyone tell me how this can be resolved or what would be the ideal temp space to be allocated for this volume of data?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle uses that space to build temporary result sets and perform sorts. The amount of space required depends on the precise explain plain of your query (check it out and it should give you some clues), but could be several times the actual amount of data in the tables if there are joins. The number of records matters not at all; it's about the *size* of the records and what Oracle is trying to do with them. You want to avoid full table scans, unnecessary sorts, and that sort of thing. Make sure your table statistics are up to date. In the end, it needs what it needs and all you can do is increase your TEMP tablespace size until it works.

Comment: we tried giving around 670 GB much higher than the explain plan suggested one but still it dint work, it throws the same error. Can you suggest any more idea

Comment: All you can do is refactor your merge to affect fewer rows at a time (assuming that will reduce the size of any temporary result sets), or add more space. Could you post your explain plan?

Comment: I am unable to post the explanation plain here, can u suggest an alternative way on how to post it?

Comment: As it to your original question text, not as a comment. Please format it as code. If you can, also post the merge command.

Comment: Also, are there any triggers on the target table?

Comment: there are no triggers on the table

Comment: The above is the explain plan details, sorry for the alignment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231874/discussion-between-karthik-and-pmdba).

Comment: You should edit the original question to include the explain plan and query. Don't add them as comments. That way it's easier for everyone to find, and you can format them appropriately.